# Is there a prayer for seeing an ambulance?

Tags: tefilla, medicine, choleh-sick

Every once in a while, you'll see an ambulance drive by, sirens wailing and everything. You stop, and wonder to yourself if everything will be okay. (*especially if the ambulance belongs to [Hatzalah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hatzalah)*)

This is probably a good time to offer up a prayer for the well-being of the unknown patient. You could probably say something in English, but [Hebrew is better](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1672/5323). You wouldn't be wrong for saying "אחינו כל בית ישראל," which is the general prayer for people in distress, but it feels a little too *vague*.

**Has anyone composed a prayer for one who sees an ambulance driving past?**

Comment: I'm not sure whether I'd want original compositions, but it really depends on the quality of the piece. Let's see what comes up.

Comment: Why not just say some Tehilim?

Comment: If you are short on time say "Hashem please heal the person who needs healing"

Comment: Very good Q! Offhand, I wonder if you can say a short version of *Mi Sheberach L'cholim* substituting a phrase such as *hacholeh* with no specific name. Sadly, I know someone 2 blocks away who occasionally has diabetic "spells". When I see Hatzalah pass my home, if I can, I rush out & see if the ambulance turns down his block. If it does, I rush over.

Answer (score 7):

R Telushkin asks exactly this question in one of his earlier books (I believe it is [The book of Jewish values](http://a.co/feqRC72) but can check if important to someone). He is quoted [here](http://velveteenrabbi.blogs.com/blog/2005/11/urjbiennial_wha.html)

> Rabbi Telushkin mentioned something that happens in Manhattan:
>   conversations are shattered by the sound of an ambulance, and he said
>   his first reaction to that was always annoyance, though he knew that
>   was the wrong reaction. **Reb Zalman suggested that when we hear
>   ambulances, we say a short prayer: El na, refa na la, "Oh God, heal
>   her."** (Moshe's prayer for Miriam, see [Bamidbar 12:13](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.12.13?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)).
>
> And Rabbi Telushkin said that when he started that practice, he
>   found immediately that he stopped feeling annoyance in response to the
>   ambulance noises, and that it expanded his consciousness. What if we
>   get stopped in traffic because there's an accident ahead? Can we
>   circumvent the impulse to be annoyed at our inconvenience, and instead
>   spend the time praying for their healing? Even if it doesn't help the
>   person in need, it might help us.

Comment: Telushkin offers very smart sensible advice. I like his suggestion. I hope in his books he also advises against rubber-necking. People who are unable to help really should not be gawking at accidents. It's really a private matter.